# Rails 3.0 . How to pass the select box value through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I knew that Rails3 no longer supporting link_to_remote.... instead of that we can modify 
the link_to method by using different syntax as follows :

link_to "Send",{:action =>"send_mail",:question_id =>question.id},:remote => true,:class =>"button small"

My problem is, in my view i keep the select box which contains the list of user's name near by send link button (which user the above syntax)... i want to pass the selection box value to link_to when user click the send button

Here is my View code :

"send_mail",:question_id =>question.id,:user_value 
=>encodeURIComponent($F('user_id'))},:remote => true,:class =>"button small" %>

I don't know how to achieve this ....can any one please suggest me on this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you be more clear?  Have you been able to do what you're trying to do in Rails 2?  Can you show what you did before?

Comment: Why not use value from the params hash in your controller action `send_mail`?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, too

Comment: In my view i don't have form element

Comment: Regardless of whether you have form element or not, the value of a form control will be available in the params hash, in your case it will be `params[:user][:id]` which you can then access in the controller. Also make sure that, id of the select tag is `user_id`.

Comment: I finally achieve this by inserting form_tag in my view and in my action i get params[:user][:id]..Thanks for your comments ..... my initial intention was passing the values with out posting a form.. but i couldn't do that as of now... any how i completed that.....

Answer (score 0):

edit: ok now is see your last comment... never mind

What I got from the question, you are looking for something like this:

http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values

It's not really a Rails problem since you can't change the Ruby code from within the rendered HTML (at least that would be very risky if it's possible). The code from above can be easily changed to your needs so that the user gets redirected to the URL that matches the button value.